# If $R$ is a commutative ring and $P$ be a prime ideal. Then $P[X]$ is never a maximal ideal of $R[X]$ even if $P$ is maximal.

Tags: ring-theory

I have been trying to solve this problem . But all the approaches I have seen assumes $R$ has unity. But that is not told in the problem. If $R$ had unity then we can use that $R[X]/P[X]$ is a field and is isomorphic to $(R/P)[X]$ and it cannot be a field .

But here I have to do it without assuming the existence of unity.

I have thought of it like this . Since a maximal ideal is a proper subset. We choose a polynomial $a(x)\in\,R$ such that $a(x)\notin P[X]$.

Then we consider the ideal $P[X] + <a(x)>$ . (It is an ideal because $P[X]$ is a prime ideal and sum of ideals is an ideal.)

And $P[X] + <a(x)>$ contains $P[X]$.

But I am having trouble showing that this ideal is a proper ideal. That is $P[X] + <a(x)>\,\,\neq R[x]$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the assumption that the ring has a $1$ is implicit in the definition of ring? A lot of authors do that.

Comment: Yeah. This is from C.Musili book. It assumes that a ring is a set which is a commutative group under addition and a semi group under multiplication and distributive laws hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an ideal $I$, prime or otherwise, notice that $J=\{p\in R[x]\,:\, p_0\in I\}$ is an ideal that contains $I[x]$, and $J\cap R=I$. Therefore $J\subsetneq R$ as soon as $I\subsetneq R$. Moreover, if there is some $r\in R\setminus I$, then $rx\in J\setminus I[x]$, which adds the other inclusion $I\subsetneq J$.

Comment: What is $p_{0}$? Is it the constant term?

Comment: It's the coefficient of degree $0$ of the polynomial $p$, as per a widely used notation.

Comment: Ah thanks. Huge help!!!.

Comment: Yeah . I was thinking the same thing. $x$ is just $1.x$. In that case how do even assume the existence of $x$ ?. Or rather how do we represent such an object?. Also we are concluding $x\notin I$ as if it did $I=R$ .But without unity how can we say that?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I would assume that the right definition is that $R[x]$ is polynomials with coefficients in $R$, but I invite you to check. The current proof works either way (if we still have that $I[x]$ is the ideal generated by $I$ in $R[x]$, whatever the latter may be).